# Using cleanup function in React UseEffect

Tags: reactjs, state, use-effect, code-cleanup

In my app there is a navbar that pops down after the user scrolled to a certain point. I use two separate navbars and define the current scroll position like this:

```
 const newNavbar = () => {
      if (window !== undefined) {
        let posHeight_2 = window.scrollY;
        posHeight_2 > 112 ? setNewNav(!newNav) : setNewNav(newNav)
      }
    };

  const stickNavbar = () => {
    if (window !== undefined) {
      let windowHeight = window.scrollY;
      windowHeight > 150 ? setSticky({ position: "fixed", top: "0", marginTop:"0", transition: "top 1s"}) : setSticky({});
    }
  };
  const scrollPos = () => {
    if (window !== undefined) {
      let posHeight = window.scrollY;
      posHeight > 112 ? setScroll(posHeight) : setScroll(0)
    }
  };
```

Current states are managed by useState and given to a class, which is triggered by the changing scroll position:

```
 const [scroll, setScroll] = useState(0);
 const [newNav, setNewNav] = useState (false)
 const [sticky, setSticky] = useState({});

 const navClass = newNav ? 'menu-2 show' : 'menu-2'
 <Navbar className={navClass}> 
  //
 </Navbar>
```

finally UseEffect to make use of the states:

```
 React.useEffect(() => {
      window.addEventListener('scroll', stickNavbar);
      return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', stickNavbar);
    }, []);
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
      window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollPos);
      return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', stickNavbar);
      }, []);
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
      window.addEventListener('scroll', newNavbar);
      return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', newNavbar);
      }, []);
```

However my cleanup functions are not working, I get the error Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second `useEffect` contains a copy/paste error.
It should remove `scrollPos` (since that's what you bound), not `stickNavbar`.

Because of this `scrollPos` listener is not removed, which causes an error on the next `scroll` event, as the bound function no longer exists after the component is removed from DOM.